# Why does setting a descriptor on a class overwrite the descriptor?

Tags: python, cpython, python-descriptors

Simple repro:

```py
class VocalDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('__get__, obj={}, objtype={}'.format(obj, objtype))
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('__set__')

class B(object):
    v = VocalDescriptor()

B.v # prints "__get__, obj=None, objtype=<class '__main__.B'>"
B.v = 3 # does not print "__set__", evidently does not trigger descriptor
B.v # does not print anything, we overwrote the descriptor
```

This question has an [effective duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273021/setting-class-attributes-does-not-use-descriptor-setter), but the duplicate was not answered, and I dug a bit more into the CPython source as a learning exercise.  Warning:  i went into the weeds.  I'm really hoping I can get help from [a captain who knows those waters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grwdjSS7D2E&t=3m10s).  I tried to be as explicit as possible in tracing the calls I was looking at, for my own future benefit and the benefit of future readers.

I've seen a lot of ink spilled over the behavior of `__getattribute__` applied to descriptors, e.g. lookup precedence.  The Python snippet in ["Invoking Descriptors"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) just below `For classes, the machinery is in type.__getattribute__()...` roughly agrees in my mind with what I believe is the corresponding [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3208-L3225) in `type_getattro`, which I tracked down by looking at ["tp_slots"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html?highlight=__setattr__#tp-slots) then [where tp_getattro is populated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3593).  And the fact that `B.v` initially prints `__get__, obj=None, objtype=<class '__main__.B'>` makes sense to me.

What I don't understand is, why does the assignment `B.v = 3` blindly overwrite the descriptor, rather than triggering `v.__set__`?  I tried to trace the CPython call, starting once more from ["tp_slots"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html?highlight=__setattr__#tp-slots), then looking at [where tp_setattro is populated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3594), then looking at [type_setattro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3253).  `type_setattro` [appears to be](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3286) a thin wrapper around [_PyObject_GenericSetAttrWithDict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/object.c#L1310).  And there's the crux of my confusion:  `_PyObject_GenericSetAttrWithDict` appears to have [logic that gives precedence to a descriptor's `__set__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/object.c#L1331-L1340)!!  With this in mind, I can't figure out why `B.v = 3` blindly overwrites `v` rather than triggering `v.__set__`.

Disclaimer 1:  I did not rebuild Python from source with printfs, so I'm not 
completely sure `type_setattro` is what's being called during `B.v = 3`.

Disclaimer 2:  `VocalDescriptor` is not intended to exemplify "typical" or "recommended" descriptor definition.  It's a verbose no-op to tell me when the methods are being called.

Comment: For me this prints 3 at the last line... The code works fine

Comment: Descriptors apply when accessing attributes from an *instance*, not the class itself.  To me, the mystery is why `__get__` worked at all, rather than why `__set__` didn't.

Comment: @Jab OP is expecting to still invoke the `__get__` method.  `B.v = 3` has effectively overwritten the attribute with an `int`.

Comment: @jasonharper Attribute access determines whether `__get__` is called, and the default implementations of `object.__getattribute__` and `type.__getattribute__` invoke `__get__` when using an instance or the class. *Assigning* via `__set__` is instance-only.

Comment: @jasonharper I believe descriptors' `__get__` methods are supposed to trigger when invoked from the class itself.  This is how @classmethods and @staticmethods are implemented, according to the [how-to guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods).

@Jab I'm wondering why `B.v = 3` is able to overwrite the class descriptor.  Based on the CPython implementation, I expected `B.v = 3` to also trigger `__set__`.

Comment: `B.v = 3` is equivalent to `type.__setattr__(B, "v", 3)`, which doesn't perform attribute lookup and so doesn't trigger the `__set__` method.

Comment: `B.v`, on the other hand, is `type.__getattribute__(B, "v")`, which *does* invoke `__get__`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that `B.v = 3` simply overwrites the descriptor with an integer (as it should).  In the descriptor protocol, [`__get__` is designed to be called as instance attribute or class attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__), but `__set__` is designed to be called only as instance attribute.

For `B.v = 3` to invoke a descriptor, the descriptor should have been defined on the metaclass, i.e. on `type(B)`.

```
>>> class BMeta(type): 
...     v = VocalDescriptor() 
... 
>>> class B(metaclass=BMeta): 
...     pass 
... 
>>> B.v = 3 
__set__
```

To invoke the descriptor on `B`, you would use an instance: `B().v = 3` will do it.

The reason for `B.v` also invoking the getter is to allow user's customization of what `B.v` does, independently of whatever `B().v` does. A common pattern is to allow direct access on the descriptor instance, by returning the descriptor itself when a class attribute access was used:

```
class VocalDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        print('__get__, obj={}, objtype={}'.format(obj, objtype))
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('__set__')
```

Now `B.v` would return some instance like `<mymodule.VocalDescriptor object at 0xdeadbeef>` which you can interact with. It is literally the descriptor object, defined as a class attribute, and its state `B.v.__dict__` is shared between all instances of `B`.

Of course it is up to user's code to define exactly what they want `B.v` to do, returning `self` is just the common pattern. A [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) is an example of a descriptor which does something different here, see the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for a pure-python implementation of `classmethod`.

Unlike `__get__`, which can be used to customize `B().v` and `B.v` independently, `__set__` is not invoked unless the attribute access is on an instance. I would suppose that the goal of customizing `B().v = other` and `B.v = other` using the same descriptor `v` is not common or useful enough to complicate the descriptor protocol further, especially since the latter is still possible with a metaclass descriptor anyway, as shown in `BMeta.v` above.

Comment: @wim Magnificent!!  In parallel I was looking once more at the type_setattro call chain.  I see that the call to [_PyObject_GenericSetAttrWithDict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L3286) supplies the type (at that point B, in my case).

Comment: Within `_PyObject_GenericSetAttrWithDict`, it [pulls the Py_TYPE of B](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/object.c#L1313) as `tp`, which is B's metaclass (`type` in my case), then it's the _metaclass_ `tp` that is treated by the [descriptor short-circuiting logic](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/object.c#L1331-L1340).  So the descriptor defined directly on `B` _is not_ seen by that short-circuiting logic (therefore in my original code `__set__` is not called), but a descriptor defined on the metaclass _is_ seen by the short-circuiting logic.

Comment: Therefore, in your case where the metaclass has a descriptor, the `__set__` method of that descriptor _is_ called.

Comment: “The reason for `B.v` invoking the getter is to allow returning the descriptor instance itself.” I disagree with this. The descriptor instance is returned anyway if the descriptor does not have a `__get__` method, so the `__get__` call on the class descriptor was not introduced for that. The reason for calling `__get__` in this case is precisely to allow a different behaviour than returning the descriptor instance, for example returning a method bound to the class, like `classmethod` does (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790797/2326961)).

Comment: @Maggyero Yeah, although I had mentioned *Of course it is up to user's code to define exactly what they want B.v to do, returning self is just the common pattern*, the part before was poorly worded.  Updated.

Answer (score 4):

Barring any overrides, `B.v` is equivalent to `type.__getattribute__(B, "v")`, while `b = B(); b.v` is equivalent to `object.__getattribute__(b, "v")`. Both definitions invoke the `__get__` method of the result if defined.

Note, thought, that the call to `__get__` differs in each case. `B.v` passes `None` as the first argument, while `B().v` passes the instance itself. In both cases `B` is passed as the second argument.

`B.v = 3`, on the other hand, is equivalent to `type.__setattr__(B, "v", 3)`, which does *not* invoke `__set__`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that none of the current answers actually answer your question.

> Why does setting a descriptor on a class overwrite the descriptor?

Setting or deleting an attribute on a class (or on a subclass of the class) owning a descriptor (e.g. `cls.descr = 3` or `del cls.descr`) overrides that descriptor because it would be impossible to change a faulty descriptor otherwise (e.g. `descr.__set__(None, cls, 3)` or `descr.__delete__(None, cls)` raising an exception) since a class dictionary (e.g. `cls.__dict__`) is a read-only [`types.MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType). You can always define a descriptor on the metaclass if you want to override setting or deleting an attribute on a class which is an instance of that metaclass. So `__set__` and `__delete__` are always passed an instance of the class owning the descriptor, that is why they do not have an `owner` parameter.

Getting an attribute on a class (or on a subclass of the class) owning a descriptor (e.g. `cls.descr`) does not override that descriptor because it does not prevent changing a faulty descriptor (e.g. `descr.__get__(None, cls)` raising an exception). So `__get__` is passed either an instance of the class owning the descriptor, or the class (or a subclass of the class) itself, that is why it has an `owner` parameter.

More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790797/2326961).